# Configure DbContext for OpenIddict

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, openid-connect, aspnet-contrib, openiddict

I'm using [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core) for JWT token authentication in my .NET Core app. I've followed [this tutorial](http://capesean.co.za/blog/asp-net-5-jwt-tokens/) but I am now receiving the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider...
```

My `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        Configuration = builder.Build();

        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
             .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
                 options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:MyDbContext:ConnectionString"]));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddOpenIddictCore<Application>(config => config.UseEntityFramework());

        services.AddMvc();

        // for seeding the database with the demo user details
        //services.AddTransient<IDatabaseInitializer, DatabaseInitializer>();
        services.AddScoped<OpenIddictManager<ApplicationUser, Application>, CustomOpenIddictManager>();
    }
```

Not sure what to do about this as I can't add a DbContext when using `AddIdentity`.

My connection string is fine, everything was working before adding OpenIddict.

**UPDATE**
Here is my `appsettings.json` file:

```
    {
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "my connection string"
    },
    "SaleboatContext": {
      "ConnectionString": "my connection string"
    }
  }
}
```

My DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser { }

public partial class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your DB context? I'd like to make sure the connection string is correctly flowed up to EntityFramework.

Comment: My connection string is not in my dbcontext, it's in my appsettings.json

Comment: Where your connection string is configured is not really important. I just want to make sure your context has the right constructor to allow external configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to a design change in EntityFramework Core RC2, you now need to flow the `DbContextOptions` manually or configure your connection string directly in `OnModelCreating`.

Try adding this constructor to your DB context (that should derive from `OpenIddictContext`):

```
public partial class MyDbContext : OpenIddictContext<ApplicationUser> {
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you friend, I'll check this out shortly

Comment: Issue I'm having with this is that ApplicationDbContext is not defined, not sure how to proceed with implementing this.

Comment: Oops, bad copy/paste. Of course, you must name it as your context class, since it's a constructor. Sorry for that.

Comment: This worked, thanks. I don't suppose you feel like sparing a few minutes to help a .net core newbie get through some of the growing pains?

Comment: If you have questions, feel free to ask them on SO using the `asp.net-core` tag and I'll take a look ;)